# Does phase lead or lag in a plasma?

Tags: plasma-physics

Plasmas have an index of refraction less than 1. So say you sent one beam of light through a plasma and another one along a path just as long but in free space. Is the plasma beam's phase lead or lag the free space beam's phase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In classical plasmas, light waves with a frequency higher than the plasma frequency have a phase velocity higher that the speed of light in vacuum $c$ (see [this](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waves/node48.html)). It means that the phase *leads* compared to light in vacuum. The group velocity, however, is lower than $c$.